# How can you remove a field from a word document?

Tags: c#, ms-word, field

I'm working on a project where the user can insert data into a document using fields, document properties and variables. The user also needs to be able to remove the data from the document. So far, I've managed to remove the document property and variable, but I'm not sure how I would go about removing the field (that's already inserted into the document). Note that I need to compare the field to a string, and if it matches; delete it from the doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using .NET Interop with Word. In that case, I believe you're looking for [`Field.Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.field.delete%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

This is of course also assuming you know how to get the field you're looking for, which would usually be enumerating through [`_Document.Fields`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.fields%28v=office.11%29.aspx) (or a more finite range if you know one) until you get the right one.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your response. I'm currently enumerating through all the document fields, but how do I read the field information? For example: {DOCPROPERTY MyField /*Mergeformat*/} How would I be able to get the "MyField" programmatically? I cannot find the right property in my field to compare it to.

Comment: @Kevin van Zanten - Is `Field.Code.Text` what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed, thank you to you as well sir!

Comment: @Kevin van Zanten - Sure thing. Interop can be a bit annoying (and the documentation is rather trial-and-error-ish at times). Sometimes it's just worth setting a breakpoint and playing around with intellisense in the immediate window until you find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The `Field` has a `Delete` method. See the documentation for [Field.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.field.delete%28office.11%29.aspx).

So I think something like this would work:

```
foreach(Field f in ActiveDocument.Fields)
{
    f.Select();
    if(f.Type == TypeYouWantToDelete)
    {
        d.Delete();
    }
}
```